# Acessando a sub-coleção no snapshot.data

Tags: firebase, flutter, firestore

Olá, eu construo um `ListView` com um `FutureBuilder`.
Mas preciso acessar uma sub-coleção, depois um documento e obter um campo do documento.
Mas retorna *null*, como faço isso?

Por exemplo: Para obter o campo **test** do documento, eu faço: 
`snapshot.data[index].data["test"]`

mas para entrar na sub_coleção, *document* e obter o campo de **test**, não posso fazê-lo da maneira normal (que é usado pelo Hasura)

```
snapshot.data[index].data["sub_collection"]["document"]["test"]
```

Meu código até agora

**getEstabelecimentos:**

```
    Future getEstabelecimentos() async {

  var firestore = Firestore.instance;

  QuerySnapshot dados =
      await firestore.collection("estabelecimentos").getDocuments();

  return dados.documents;
}
```

**FutureBuilder:**

```
Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getEstabelecimentos(),
                builder: (_, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return new Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 15),
                        Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                Colors.blue),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(30)),
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                    print(snapshot.data[index].data["name"]);
                                    print(snapshot.data[index].data["category"]);
                                    return GestureDetector(
                                      child: makeItem(nome: snapshot.data[index], categoria: snapshot.data[index].data["categoria"], checkins: snapshot.data[index].data["sub_colecao"]["documento"]['teste']),
                                      onTap: () => {},
                                    );
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ));
                  }
                }),
          )
```